# Issue migrating from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2017 Standard (on Linux)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, linux, migration, sql-server-2017

I am currently trying to carry out a database migration from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2017 (Linux) using the DMA tool.

I get the all green after running the assessment, however I get hit with an "out of memory" exception during the migration process.

Any advice on how I can resolve this issue? Both source and destination servers have 16GBs of RAM. This should be sufficient, no?

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar, but not exactly the same, question here:

[Azure SQL Data Migration Assistant is Stuck on "Migrate Data"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192534/azure-sql-data-migration-assistant-is-stuck-on-migrate-data)

However, it does explain the limitation you're hitting:

> The Extract service connects to a database, reads all of its objects and their properties, and then creates an in-memory model of the database.

If the database you're trying to migrate has an exceptional number of schema objects, this in-memory DAC model potentially overwhelms the client application / system (Data Migration Assistant running on your PC in this case), resulting in the OutOfMemoryException.

Your next best bet would be to use tried and true approaches like backup / restore in order to migrate to the new machine.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I resolved the issue. I took the backup/restore route after the DMA tool did not work. I was restoring the backup made on SQL Server 2008 to Server 2017(Linux version), and I get this error at the tail end of the restore process.

> There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query. Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server solarwinds-DB2, Line 1 RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Apparently, this issue has been encountered by a number of people trying to do same (seems to be a bug). The workaround was to restore the database to SQL Server 2017 (Windows version), take a backup, and then do the restore to SQL Server 2017 (Linux version). It works now.

Comment: Sorry, I read that we can't backup/restore from sql server 2008 (100) to sql server 2017. were you able to do this ? just a backup/restore?